# Eloquent model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

`Project` model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'project';
    protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';   
}
```

`Developer` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Developer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'developer';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

I want to join this two model as the SQL below :

```
SELECT developer.developer_name, count(project.dev_id)
    FROM project
    JOIN developer ON developer.id = project.dev_id
    GROUP BY developer.developer_name
```

Can someone help me? I am confused when looked through different documentation.

Please guide me the correct way.

Comment: Whats the logic behind `protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';`, I haven't read further.

Comment: this one is just declare the primary key of the project table is project_id

Comment: I know what it does, why don't you use `id` as everyone else in a first place? You seem to get it for the `Developer` model.

Comment: @Kyslik because it is the foreign key of another table..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below query and also you can do this by eloquent query for this you have to define relationship in model.

```
DB::table('project')
->join('developer', 'project.dev_id', '=', 'developer.id')
->select('developer.developer_name', DB::raw("count(project.dev_id) as count"))
->groupBy('developer.developer_name')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Create a `projects` relation in `Developer` model.

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Project::class, 'dev_id')
}
```

Then you can get all developers with number of projects they are handling using

```
Developer::withCount('projects')->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but may i know where to put Developer::withCount('projects')->get(); ?

Comment: In your controller

Comment: Thansk your suggestion